# Multiple HTTP Connections (Segmented/Swarm Downloading) to download the same file in Android

Tags: android, http, download

I'm currently working on creating a Download Manager for Android. In order to optimize the download I need to download the same file using multiple connections to the server. (ie. the same technique used in Internet Download Manager used in Windows.)
The thing is I don't know how to create several HTTP connections and download the same file. I hope you can help me.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spawn off a few threads which request part of the file via the Header `Content-Range` keyword.  see [Reading the first part of a file using HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004675/reading-the-first-part-of-a-file-using-http)